# n-gram probabilities in language modeling

Tags: probability

I am reading [these notes](http://web.mit.edu/6.863/www/fall2012/readings/ngrampages.pdf) on natural processsing, specifically n-grams. On the first page, the author argues

that we should assign a higher probability to a sequence of words such as "...all of a sudden I notice three

guys standing on the sidewalk..." compared to the following sequence of the same words "on guys all I of notice

sidewalk three a sudden standing the". Then the author discusses the n-gram model which uses the chain rule of probability to compute the probability of a sequence of words. However, the chain rule of probability is order agnostic, i.e. if there are three words, $w_1, w_2, w_3$ then by the chain rule of probability to $P(w_1,w_2,w_3) = P((w_3,w_2,w_1) = P(w_2,w_1,w_3)$ and so on for the other three permutations. So I don't understand how an n-gram model takes this into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A word isn't an event, so $P(w_1,w_2,w_3)$ makes no sense. If you phrase that more carefully, I think you may find that you confused the order of the arguments with the order of the words, which is encoded in the events; this isn't apparent from your formulation because you ignored the distinction between the words and the events.